# Get ServletMapping in WebsocketAdapter [Jetty]

Tags: java, websocket, embedded-jetty

I need the Path of the Websocket-Connection without the prefix in my WebsocketAdapter.

F.E. the Prefix given in the web.xml is:

```
<servlet-mapping> 
    <url-pattern>
       /test/
    </url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>
```

Now i open a Websocket with the Path

> localhost:8080/test/this-is-the-path-i-need

In the future i dont want to change my Java-Server-Code after changing the url-pattern.

I create my WebsocketAdapter within a WebSocketCreator called by the configure-function in WebsocketServlet.

Depending on my research i think i could get it with ServletMapping.getPathSpec(). The Problem with that is that i have no Idea how to get the ServletMapping.

Any Ideas how to solve this? (Not restricted to the possible solution with ServletMapping)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note: your url-pattern of `/test/` would never match for a URI of `localhost:8080/test/this-is-the-path-i-need`, as that URI is not a match.
>   If you wanted to to have that URI match, then you would use the url-pattern of `/test/*` and then the `request.pathInfo` would have what you need/want.

The mapping from your `WEB-INF/web.xml` that was used to access your servlet/filter/websocket is not accessible from within the webapp using the standard Servlet APIs.

Using the Servlet APIs you capture the as-used full path or URI and then strip out the Servlet context path prefix from it to get the path that was used.

To do this, you will use standard Servlet `HttpServletRequest` from the [`ServletUpgradeRequest.getHttpServletRequest()`](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/9.4.10.v20180503/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/servlet/ServletUpgradeRequest.html#getHttpServletRequest--), collect the path, remove the context path prefix, optionally collect the pathInfo, and then pass that resulting path into your `WebsocketAdapter` that you just created.

> Note: `ServletMapping` is an internal class to Jetty.
>   It's not a public/formal API, so its use is discouraged for your declared use case of *"In the future i dont want to change my Java-Server-Code..."*.

If you still want to use internal APIs, I would recommend skipping `ServletMapping` entirely and just going for the as-used `PathSpec` for this specific request, you can access it via the `ServletUpgradeRequest` attributes.

```java
public static class MyPathSpecCreator implements WebSocketCreator
{
    private static final String PATHSPEC_KEY = PathSpec.class.getName();

    @Override
    public Object createWebSocket(ServletUpgradeRequest upgradeRequest,
                                  ServletUpgradeResponse upgradeResponse)
    {
        String pathSpecPattern = "/"; // default value (pick your own)
        PathSpec pathSpec = (PathSpec) upgradeRequest.getServletAttribute(PATHSPEC_KEY);
        if(pathSpec != null)
            pathSpecPattern = pathSpec.getDeclaration();
        return new MyWebSocketAdapter(pathSpecPattern);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, thank you Joakim Erdfelt for your fast and good solution!